# Display updated time each seconds in react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It must be a function, it can't be a class (class is able to do it in the componentDidMount with setInterval)

I set up something like this

```
function DisplayTime() {
  let time = new Date().getTime();
  setInterval(() => {
    time = new Date().getTime();
  }, 1000);
  return time;
}
ReactDOM.render(<DisplayTime />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The problem is function can run only once, so the time won't able to get update. Something like `setInterval(() => {ReactDOM.render(...), ...})` low efficient, which is not acceptable.

Any idea?

===
useState is advanced solution, any solution without using most recent version of React?

Comment: You haven't supplied the actual time interval to `setInteval()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, thanks for pointing out; but that's minor issue (i fixed now). My main problem is how to construct a function which could keep update after render?

Comment: You can run that func more than once. Just do a clearInterval and then call it again.

Comment: You need a component with the state, which updates the state every minute hence re-renders.

Comment: @zerkms, yes, you are right, so that's what I was asking. How to create such component? The component must use function as I said.

Comment: @WeijingJayLin the component you describe is by definition stateful. The two ways to do stateful components in React are to either use a class or use the new Hooks features that were explicitly created to allow you to use state without writing a class. There is no way to do what you want without using the features that were created to let you do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().getTime());
  setInterval(() => {
    setTime(new Date().getTime());
  }, 1000);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{time}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: useState is advanced, any other solution? I would still mark your answer

Comment: @WeijingJayLin why don't you learn React using any of millions of available tutorials or the official documentation? Begging to implement it for you does not make you a better developer

Answer (score 0):

You can use ref to avoid update state frequently. Try next example:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const currentTimeRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateCurrentTime = () => {
      const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      if (currentTimeRef.current) {
        currentTimeRef.current.textContent = currentTime;
      }
    };

    // Update the time initially
    updateCurrentTime();

    // Update the time every second
    const intervalId = setInterval(updateCurrentTime, 1000);

    // Clear the interval when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Current Time:</h1>
      <p ref={currentTimeRef}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```